# VBA: Importing data to new Sheet in Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure there's a really simple method I'm missing to achieve this, but I'm not sure which. I'm trying to import data files in .txt format to new sheets in my current workbook. Almost there, but I'm opening a new workbook instead of a new sheet in the current one. Ideally I'd also select several files at once, but I'm happy if it works with one at a time too. Help? Thank you!!

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim vFileName

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")

If vFileName = False Or Right(vFileName, 3) <> "txt" Then
    GoTo BeforeExit
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vFileName, _
Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, _
Local:=True

BeforeExit:
Worksheets("Intro").Activate
Exit Sub

ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume BeforeExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim vFileName As Variant
Dim i As Byte 'if you are goint to select more than 254 files, change this to Integer or whatever you need


vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , , , True)


On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
If IsError(vFileName) = True Or Right(vFileName, 3) <> "txt" Then
    GoTo BeforeExit
End If

GotFiles:
For i = 1 To UBound(vFileName) Step 1
    'maybe you will need to modify the code below to adapt it to your exportation needs
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & vFileName(i), Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next i

Exit Sub

BeforeExit:
Worksheets("Intro").Activate
Exit Sub

ErrorHandle:
If Err.Number = 13 Then GoTo GotFiles
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume BeforeExit

End Sub
```